# Web url cannot be empty for url type button

Tags: botframework

```
 var msg = context.MakeMessage();


            msg.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

            SigninCard card = new SigninCard()
            {
                 Text= "link it",

                Buttons = new List<CardAction>
                         {
                             new CardAction
                            {

                                Value = "account linking url https",
                                Type = "account_link",
                                Title = "Link"

                            },

                        }
            };

            msg.Attachments.Add(card.ToAttachment());


 await context.PostAsync(msg);
```

I'm trying to use SignInCard to link Facebook account. 
This error appears:

> {"error":{"message":"(#100) Web url cannot be empty for url type
>   button","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2018041,"fbtrace_id":"GclYUUuTL2D"}}

But there is a string https url in url field.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.

```
var msg = context.MakeMessage();


            dynamic messageData = new JObject();
            messageData.attachment = new JObject();
            messageData.attachment.type = "template";
            messageData.attachment.payload = new JObject();
            messageData.attachment.payload.template_type = "generic";


            messageData.attachment.payload.elements
                = new JArray(
                    new JObject(
                        new JProperty("title", "title"),
                        new JProperty("subtitle", "Link your account"),
                        new JProperty("buttons",
                            new JArray(
                                new JObject(
                                    new JProperty("type", "account_link"),
                                    new JProperty("url", "yourUrl")
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );


            msg.ChannelData = messageData;


                await context.PostAsync(msg);
```

Comment: I hit the same issue today. A bit crazy that you have to use channel-specific data to get around it, no? The HeroCard should be channel-agnostic. Is there a GitHub issue filed, would you know?

Comment: Update: I was using 'Type=ActionTypes.MessageBack'. When I switched to 'Type=ActionType.ImBack', it worked. I think a similar enum change would work for you - answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get into channel-specific `ChannelData`. In your `SigninCard`'s Buttons initializer, instead of

```
Type = "account_link",
```

use

```
Type = ActionTypes.Signin,
```

Worked on my Facebook Messenger channel.